# How to render a Rails view into a string in a feature spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing, wicked-pdf

In an RSpec feature spec (integration test) for a Rails 5.2.2 app, I would like to render a view into a string that I need for further processing into a PDF file (using [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org) and the [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) gem).

I am struggling to render a Rails view into a string.

I have tried this:

```
something = create :something # A FactoryBot factory
controller = SomeThingsController.new
view = controller.render_to_string '/some_things/show.pdf.haml',
    locals: { :@something => something }
```

This sort of works, but fails where my view attempts to use the `root_url` which is not defined as there is no valid HTTP request.

There are numerous vaguely related questions, but they all (to my knowledge) either refer to ancient Rails versions or are not related to feature tests.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself... I post it here if others have the same problem.

In the feature test with RSpec and Capybara, the page content is accessible as `page.html`, which in my case contains the valid PDF.

```
something = create :something # A FactoryBot factory
visit something_path(something)
pdf = page.html
```